# Using R for financials

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I am trying to use:

```
library(pdfetch)
tickers <- c('FB','YHOO'.....etc long list of tickers)
pdfetch_YAHOO(tickers, fields = c("adjclose"),
    from = as.Date("2017-04-01"),
    to = as.Date("2017-04-30"))
```

My code isn't working though. If someone could show me how to output this info to a chart, I would be extremely grateful!!

Comment: The error that i keep getting is the following: Error in fr[, match(fields, valid.fields) + 1] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I didn't have any issues with querying using `pdfetch()`. I did only use 2 symbols, rather than 7000. So many you'll need to split your list of 7000 into smaller data frames and then put them together.

Comment: is there a way to efficiently cut up this data and then splice it together, rather than copying and pasting it to excel? if i split my data into frames of 50, that methodology willtake a very very long time.... thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I would consider using the quantmod package. It will construct OHLC objects for each of the tickers you plug into it. I would then use dygraphs or highcharter to put them into a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not exactly sure what the goal of this exercise is, but I'll take a crack. I'm going to use the quantmod library since I know it. What I do here is set up a list of tickers, get those tickers, create a function which munges the data, convert that data to an xts object of closing values, and plug it into dygraphs, which automatically interprets xts data.

```
library(dygraphs)
library(quantmod)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

tickers <- c('FB','YHOO')

temp <- getSymbols(tickers,
          from = as.Date("2001-04-01"),
          to = as.Date("2017-04-30"))

munge_data <- function(tickers){

  data <- lapply(tickers, get) %>% 
    lapply(as.data.table) %>% 
    lapply(function(df) setnames(df, colnames(df),
                                 c("Date","Open","High",
                                   "Low","Close","Volume",
                                   "Adjusted")))
  names(data) <- tickers

  rbindlist(data,idcol = T)

}

my_data <- tickers %>% 
  munge_data %>% 
  .[,.(Date,.id,Close)] %>% 
  dcast(...~.id, value.var = "Close") %>% 
  as.xts.data.table()

dygraph(my_data)
```

This will take an arbitrary amount of tickers and plot them (although differentiating 7000 ticker symbols is going to be impossible on a graph).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to plotting with ggplot2. We download the data into a list where each element is a ticker symbol. The we convert it to a data frame. Inside the call to ggplot, we convert the data from wide to long format and scale the data so that all close values are relative to the close value on the first day of the period. This puts every stock on the same scale:

```
library(pdfetch)
library(tidyverse)
library(xts)

tickers = c('FB','YHOO','GENE','AAPL','MSFT','LUV','AMZN','AIV','BUD','HPQ','XOM','UAL')

# Download tickers into a list
df = map(tickers, function(tt) {
  pdfetch_YAHOO(tt, fields = c("adjclose"),
                from = as.Date("2017-04-01"),
                to = as.Date("2017-04-30")) 
}) 

# Convert to a data frame
df = do.call(cbind, df)
df = data.frame(date=as.Date(index(df)), df)

# Convert data frame to long format and plot
ggplot(gather(df, ticker, close, -date) %>% 
         group_by(ticker) %>%
         mutate(close=close/close[1]), 
       aes(date, close)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, colour="grey30", size=0.2) +
  geom_line(size=0.4) +
  facet_grid(~ ticker) +
  theme_classic(base_size=9) +
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.94, 1.06), breaks=seq(0,2,0.05)) +
  labs(x="April") +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

You could also use color to show when a stock goes below/above its value at the start of the month. For that we use interpolation so that color always changes when a line crosses 1. We also go with an even more minimal theme.

```
# Dates to interpolate at
dts = seq(min(df$date), max(df$date), length=500)

# Create an interpolated data frame (note this data frame will have 7000*500 rows if
# you do this for 7000 symbols (not that you'd want to plot that many stocks 
# at once anyway)
df.interp = gather(df, ticker, close, -date) %>%
  split(. , .$ticker) %>%
  map_df(~ data.frame(approx(.x$date, .x$close, xout=dts), ticker=.x$ticker[1])) %>%
  rename(date=x, close=y)

ggplot(df.interp %>% 
         group_by(ticker) %>%
         mutate(close=close/close[1]), 
       aes(date, close, colour=close > 1, group=ticker)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, colour="grey30", size=0.2) +
  geom_line(size=0.6) +
  facet_grid(~ ticker) +
  theme_classic(base_size=9) +
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.line.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.94, 1.06), breaks=seq(0,2,0.05)) +
  labs(x="April 2017") +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide me with such an in-depth answer, this is amazing! For some reason, whenever i try and download the tickers into a list I get the following error: " Error in fr[, match(fields, valid.fields) + 1] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions"  any idea what could be going on here? thanks again!!!

Comment: Ugh - I have been playing with this code for a solid two hours - and for some reason - anytime i put more than about 10 tickers in my list it says "Error in fr[, match(fields, valid.fields) + 1] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions"  ..... not sure why this is happening. If you have any advice at all i would really appreciate it it, thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the download problems. This was the first time I've used `pdfetch`. Have you tried with `quantmod`?